# how to show proccess like in ps -e

Tags: c, linux, shell, command, proc

Hello!

I wanto to make simple c proggram what will work like ps -e. The only colums that should be shown are PID and CMD. Thats my code:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>
int main()
{
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *entry;
if ((dir = opendir("/proc")) == NULL)
perror("operation error");
else 
{
printf("PID      CMD\n");
while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
printf("  %s\n", entry->d_name);
closedir(dir);
}
return 0; 
}
```

My questins are:

1) How i can show only folders with numbers(i don't know how to implement regcomp())?

2)How to near PID write CMD (I can't glue(?) strings with path if is folder with number)?

Comment: Try to read into the /proc folder. There you may found some files of path /{pid}/stat containing intersting things (where pid is the process pid - a number)

Comment: You mean restrict the search to only directories whose name is all numeric? Just scan it for a character which isn't a number.

Comment: Yes, into the folder /proc there're some folder named with numbers. They're the PIDs of the processes in execution. In each {pid} folder there's a text file named stat.

Comment: @tripleee wchich command is good for that?

Comment: @SergioFormiggini how to add variable to path?

Comment: You have to scan the directory /proc, inside /proc to scan the directories having numeric values and then you have to read the file stat.

Comment: If you executes a line (in example) like: `cat /proc/{pid}/stat` you'll see the contents of the file stat. This file contains the info you are looking for.

Comment: Why do you need to add a variable to the path? Which SO are you working on?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu, because i want read file comm(there is  name of procces i need)

Comment: @Bombozaur666 Use [`strspn()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strspn/). Use this to search for the span of numeric characters in the name. If it's all numeric, this will be the same as the length.

Comment: i don;t know how to read if i dont give /path/ {pid} / comm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an hint ... Try to develop your code starting from this! :)

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int readData(char *dirname);

int readData(char *dirname)
{
    FILE * file;
    char buffer[1024]={0};

    sprintf(buffer,"/proc/%s/stat",dirname);

    file = fopen(buffer,"r");
    if (!file)
        return errno;

    while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),file))
        puts(buffer);

    if (file)
        fclose(file);

    return errno;
}

int main(void)
{
    DIR * dir;

    struct dirent * entry;

    if ( (dir = opendir("/proc")) == NULL )
        perror("operation error");

    while ((entry = readdir(dir))) {
        if ( strlen(entry->d_name) == strspn(entry->d_name, "0123456789"))
            if (readData(entry->d_name))
                break;
    }

    if (dir)
        closedir(dir);

    return errno;
}
```