# How to print out process name if i know the pid using c?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

> Create a lab_ps.c program, which prints all running process like in ps
>   -e.
>
> Hints:
>
> The list of all processes can be found in /proc; Check the proc manual
>   (man proc). Print two columns: PID and CMD.

This is my task. I wrote a code where i get pid from /proc directory.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    if ((dir = opendir("/proc")) == NULL)
        perror("opendir error");
    else
    {
      printf("Pid:\n");

      while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {       if (entry->d_name[0] == '1' || entry->d_name[0] == '2'
                || entry->d_name[0] == '3' || entry->d_name[0] == '4'
                || entry->d_name[0] == '5' || entry->d_name[0] == '6'
                || entry->d_name[0] == '7' || entry->d_name[0] == '8'
                || entry->d_name[0] == '9') //used to find pid
                {
                        printf("  %s\n", entry->d_name);
                        if(fork() == 0)
                        {
                                execlp("cat", "cat", "/proc/",entry->d_name, NULL);
                        }
                        else
                                wait(NULL);
                }
        }
      closedir(dir);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How can i translate pid to process name in c?

Comment: See if [this](https://superuser.com/questions/632979/if-i-know-the-pid-number-of-a-process-how-can-i-get-its-name) helps.

Comment: Have you actually checked `man proc` as suggested? It's pretty clear.

Comment: You solution is way too complex. You don't need to start new processes at all. Walking `/proc` is not needed too. Just read `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` and that is it.

Comment: but pid is changing how can i put a variable into directory adress to read it?

Comment: Processes don't have names - what `ps` shows is the name of the *executable* of the process.  That can be found using `readlink()` of the appropriate `/proc/$pid/exe`.  BTW, have a look at `isdigit()` in the C Standard Library - that can reduce the length of that `if` statement!

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439782/how-to-show-proccess-like-in-ps-e/47477154#47477154 . The function `readData()` receives the pid as a string0 value and prints info relavant to it.

Comment: I think that the answer I posted in the link indicated in the previous message is quite the code you are searching for!